# Adding 8va line (both high or low) in Sibelius 7 doesn't play back

Tags: software, sibelius, ottava

I'm working with Sibelius 7 and even though I'm adding 8va lines at some parts of my score, when playing it back I get the same sound I should be getting if I didn't have them.

Any ideas why this could be happening?

Comment: Does it happen when you begin the playback *before* the 8va lines?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just tried it (version 7.1.3) and it played back an octave higher. I selected Notations, Lines, Octave Lines, 8va, then clicked on the note where it started. You can drag the bar out as far as you want the effect. After it's there, you can  click on the 8va, then press control-shift-i to make sure it's set for playback.

If you still have trouble, there's a good Sibelius forum that could probably help:

http://www.sibelius.com/cgi-bin/helpcenter/chat/chat.pl

Answer (score 4):

Sibelius doesn't play it back one octave higher when you click on the note.
You have to start the playback ("P") from the bar where the 8va sign begins.
If you start the playback in the middle of the 8va, it won't be rendered.

I came here from Google, didn't find any solution if not by myself.